# How to add default class on :class?

Tags: vue.js

I have following code:

```
<div class="LngList" v-for="(lang, index) in languages">
  <button @click="clickOnLanguage(lang.lang, index)" :class="{'ui negative basic button' : lang.isClicked }">{{lang.lang}}</button>
</div>
```

It's setting class to `ui negative basic button` if `lang.isClicked` is true. But how can I add some classes if the value is false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a property to your `class` binding that represents the classes you want to show when `lang.isClicked` is false. Then use `!lang.isClicked`.

```
:class="{'ui negative basic button' : lang.isClicked, 'other class': !lang.isClicked }"
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I bind class like : `:class="{lang.style: !lang.isClicked }`? `lang.style` is value that I can get during `for` iteration.

Comment: @user1432751 No, that wouldn't likely work. You could change to use a method though and build the class object.

Comment: class object? Could you give link\example?

Comment: @user1432751 The last example here of the `object syntax`. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to have default classes is just to set the condition to `true` like this:

```
:class="{'conditional-classes' : lang.isClicked, 'default-classes': true }"
```

Answer (score 0):

To set default classes you can also do:

```html
<button 
  class="default-class" 
  @click="clickOnLanguage(lang.lang, index)" 
  :class="{'ui negative basic button' : lang.isClicked }"
>
  {{lang.lang}}
</button>
```